# Google chrome and Mozilla firefox automatically displaying to unwanted web page whenever I find www.google.co.in

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, windows-8.1-upgrade

I'm using Widows 8.1, in that Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox automatically displaying to unwanted web page whenever I search www.google.co.in. I tried to uninstall both the software and reinstalled it. But again I am getting the same issue. Please suggest me how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: The redirection could happen at a few different locations. Does this happen with all networks?

Comment: Yes, it is happening with all the networks. When I using IE, I didn't find any issues. Only problem with Chrome and Firbox

Comment: Try opening C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts in Notepad. Do you see a line with google.co.in? It's possible this file was at one point used to redirect the website somewhere else. You might also have a userscript or extension that's doing it. There are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this happens on all networks, and with only some browsers, this is most likely an issue resulting from some software redirecting you to a different page. I would recommend running a scan with any antivirus software you have, and possibly installing other software (e.g. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware) if scanning and removing using this antivirus software does not work.